# Xcode is playing a deleted file

Tags: xcode

I were trying to play mp3 song in my iPhone game, I did it! But there is a problem! Now, only that song is able to play in my app, I try changing the name of the song in Xcode but it doesn't work!  Then, I deleted that song to try another one, and something extremely weird is happening, Xcode is still running the deleted song! I wanna know how to completely delete that song from my mac and why aren't another songs working.

Here is my delegate.m, I change the (musicamenu) but It just plays the "musicamenu" song. This musicamenu is the song I deleted!

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"musicamenu" ofType: @"mp3"];
NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:soundFilePath ];
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];
player.numberOfLoops = -1; //infinite loop
[player play];
```

Comment: Is this behavior only in the simulator? If so try resetting it.

Comment: Well, you *did* ask for it to play an infinite number of times.

Answer (score 0):

After deleting the first song and replacing it, do a clean and then try it again. Make sure you did not just delete it from xcode but also removed its reference to the project file in your Mac or wherever you placed it.